# SOAP to REST conversion : Fresh or reuse?

Tags: java, web-services, rest, soap

My team has been tasked with converting our application's existing SOAP API to REST. My preference is to re-write the API from scratch (reusing only the actual business logic that each operation performs). Others in my team want to just have REST as a wrapper over the existing SOAP. Meaning we would expose REST services but when a request comes in our application would internally call the existing SOAP operations.

Could you please offer suggestions on which of these is the best approach? It looks like my way is cleaner and lighter and faster but their way allows some code re-use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends what is your priority and weather you are going to receive too many requests for changes in behavior of API.

- Ample time and more changes expected:

> If you have got time, of course writing from scratch is recommended as
>   it would mean cleaner, lighter and faster. This will also make
>   shipping new features easy.

- Less time and less changes expected. API too big to do regression testing:

> BUT if you have time constraints, I would suggest go with REST over
>   SOAP api. Anyways you are going to expose only REST api to client, so
>   you can do internal refactoring and phasing out of SOAP as and when
>   time permits you. Changing whole code means regression testing of
>   entire module

Comment: In our case, time is limited so we decided to go with wrapper approach. Thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 1):

> Could you please offer suggestions on which of these is the best
>   approach? It looks like my way is cleaner and lighter and faster but
>   their way allows some code re-use.

I wrote a framework that does the SOAP -> REST conversion. It was used internally in one of the companies I used to work for. The framework was capable of doing this with a mapping file in less than 10 minutes, but we did not use it for all services. Here's why...

- Not all services (WSDL based) are designed with REST in mind. Some of them are just remote methods being invoked on a service and nothing more.
- The service may not have `resources` that can be mapped.
- Even if there are resources they may not map correctly to REST (GET / POST etc) and some of the calls are not easily translatable.
- A mapping framework has an overhead of it's own. The framework's SLA was quite low (single digit millis), but even a small overhead may not be suitable for critical services. The time it takes to profile and get this overhead down should not be underestimated.

In summary, the approach works for some services but it takes some engineering effort to get there. It makes sense to do this if you have say 500+ services that need to be converted quickly in a short span of time, temporarily.

Answer (score 0):

The fact that you would have to convert your REST calls to SOAP calls in order to reuse your current code definitely suggests a rewrite to me!

To make testing, debugging, and profiling easier, you should have a pure POJO based API that is called by your REST API.

What back end server are you using? As several of the more popular Java web servers have tooling that makes creating REST APIs really easy.